# Jquery Timeago NaN Years ago from .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, timeago

To start, I'm finally posting after battling for a while with this.

Basically, I'm using Socket.IO to create a messenger for a site im working on. I'm having an issue with the timeago plugin displaying NaN years ago as its output.

After googling around, i see that the timeago plugin requires a pretty specfic date format, or a Java Date() object.

Here's my code..

```
socket.on('chat.message', function (data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('system')) {
    toastr["success"](data.msg);
  } else {
    $chat.append(
      '<li class="left clearfix">' +
      '<span class="chat-img pull-left">' +
      '<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mm&amp;s=40" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" width="50" />' +
      '</span>' +

      '<div class="chat-body clearfix">' +
      '<div class="header">' +
      '<strong class="primary-font">' + data.nickname + '</strong>' +
      '<small class="pull-right text-muted time" data-time="' + data.timeSent + '">' +
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>' + $.timeago(data.timeSent) +
      '</small>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<p>' + data.msg + '</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</li>'
    );
    $('.panel-body').animate({scrollTop: $chat.height()});
  }
});

function updateTimes() {
  $('.time').each(function () {
    var time = $.timeago($(this).attr('data-time'));
    $(this).html(time);
  });
}
setInterval(function () {
  updateTimes();
}, 3000);
```

So as you can see, each message element appended onto the page has the timeago output, and the original time sent stored in an attribute for my function to update using updateTimes().

When the message is first received, everything is fine. However when i use the attribute's value and pass that to timeago, this is where everything goes wrong.

From searching around, i thought i might be able to do the follow:

```
function updateTimes() {
  $('.time').each(function() {
    var time = new Date($(this).attr('data-time'));
    $(this).html($.timeago(time));
  });
}
```

Although this didnt work either.

....Edit....

I forgot to mention how i'm setting the time at first..

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
```

Hopefully this is obvious for someone, unfortunaly my javascript knowledge is lacking!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Ok, so this has now been resolved.

Seems you can't pass Date() a string, so i had to

`var time = new Date(parseInt($(this).attr('data-time')));`

Many thanks to @amklose

Comment: In your `updateTimes` function, does it output correctly if you replace the `$(this).attr('data-time')` with an actual date string such as `"2008-07-17"`?

If so, try this and see what gets printed to the console. I have a feeling your date object might not be formatted correctly.

    var time = new Date($(this).attr('data-time'));
    console.log(time);

Comment: `function updateTimes() {
                $('.time').each(function() {
                    console.log($.timeago(new Date("2008-07-17")));
                });
            } `
Displays... "7 Years ago"

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mention how i set the time in the first place, i've updated my question to show this...

Comment: That's good, so what happens when you `console.log(time);` in that alternate updateTimes() function?

Comment: @amklose - "Invalid Date" - As mentioned above, its a timestamp im using as opposed to a date

Comment: sorry I didn't catch that. So what is the format of data.timeSent? is it a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Yeah, so i googled further, realising half where i am after you pointing me towards my invalid date..
I found this...
`var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000)`

so i tried....

`var time = new Date($(this).attr('data-time') * 1000);
                    $(this).html($.timeago(time));`

Sadly... this shows.. 7000 years ago :)

I'm getting there at least

Comment: Can you try parsing the timestamp to an int before creating the date? It looks like the Date() function takes a unix timestamp as a number, not a string. Try this: `var d = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this has now been resolved.

Seems you can't pass Date() a string, so i had to

`var time = new Date(parseInt($(this).attr('data-time')));`

Many thanks to @amklose